# Why am i getting "warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type"? Double linked list in a struct array

Tags: c, arrays, data-structures, warnings, linked-list

I'm trying to make an implementation of a double linked list which connects to an array. 
The struct that makes the array contains the list's Head and Tail pointer.

```
typedef struct myStruct{
 int code;
 struct myStruct *Head;
 struct myStruct *Tail;
}myStruct;

myStruct MyArray[10];
```

Here's my double linked list:

```
struct myList
{
 int data;
 struct myList *previous;
 struct myList *next;
}head;

struct myList *start =NULL;
```

On the following piece of code im getting the warning which i wrote on the title of the post

warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type

```
void add_neighbor_to_neighborList(struct neighborList *start,int code,int Data)
{ 
 struct myList *newNode = (struct myList *) malloc (sizeof(struct myList ));   /* creates a new node of the correct data size */
 newNode->data = Data;

 if (start == NULL) { /*WARNING!checks to see if the pointer points somewhere in space*/
  MyArray[code].Head=newNode; //WARNING
  newNode->previous=MyArray[code].Head;
 }
 else
 {
  MyArray[code].Tail->next=newNode; /*error: ‘struct myStruct’ has no member named ‘next’*/
  newNode->previous=MyArray[code].Tail; //WARNING
 }
 /*if (newNode == NULL){ 
  return NULL;
  }*/
 MyArray[code].Tail=newNode; //WARNING
 newNode->next=MyArray[code].Tail;  //WARNING

 //return *start;
}
```

I'm looking at it so much time but still cant find whats wrong and what i should correct.
If you had any idea,I would appreciate that! Thanks anyway/in advance! ;)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
MyArray[code].Head=newNode; //WARNING
```

`MyArray[code].Head`'s type is `struct myStruct *`.

`newNode`'s type is `struct myList *`.

`struct myStruct *` and `struct myList *` are pointers to two different types, they are incompatible, that's what your compiler is telling you.

---

You probably wanted your `struct myStruct` to be defined like this:

```
typedef struct myStruct{
 int code;
 struct myList *Head;
 struct myList *Tail;
} myStruct;
```

---

I'd suggest you to use more explicit type names so errors like that wouldn't happen.

You could rename your `struct myStruct` to `struct myList` and rename `struct myList` to `struct myNode`. Because it's what they are, or seem to be.

Comment: wow. i feel stupid! sth so simple and plain and i couldnt see it! Thank u very much Bertrand Marron! also thanx for the tip! ;)

Answer (score 0):

You have two different types, `myStruct` and `struct myList`.  They are not the same type (though they contain the same kind of types in the same order).  Use one or the other.

The array, `MyArray` is of `myStruct`s which contains pointers to `struct myStruct`.  You are attempting to assign a pointer to a `struct myList` to those pointers.  They are not the same hence the warning.

Comment: hm maybe i wasnt clear (im gonna edit my post). myStruct is for the struct but i want another one for my double linked list (myList). All the elements of the array (MyArray) are of this struct myStruct. Each one should have a reference to its list. So i think i cant do it with only one struct :/

Comment: @FILIaS: Bertrand definitely has it then.  You've defined the types switched so it is not what you had intended.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to assign a myList pointer to something that expects a myStruct pointer. You can't do that.

```
A* pA;
B *pB;

pB = pA; // Can't do this without casting
```